# Trying to insert text into an editor from a list of values - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to customise an editor addon a little so it inserts text into the editor. The text inserted will be '{{value-chosen}}' and the 'value-chosen' will just be a single word chosen from the dropdown list.

The dropdown list is made up from an array containing words.

When I choose the word from the dropdown e.g. 'dogs' it should insert:

{{dogs}}

but instead inserts this text:

{{function ( selector, context ) {// The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'// Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );}}}

This is the coding, it is from a plugin you can add to the editor to add more option/ buttons. It performed close to what I wanted so I modified it to work the way I needed but I get the message above inserted into the edotor.

```
keyii_name = ["8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "14", "18", "24", "30", "36", "48", "60", "72", "96"];

! function(a) {
    "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["jquery"], a) : "object" == typeof module && module.exports ? module.exports = function(b, c) {
    return void 0 === c && (c = "undefined" != typeof window ? require("jquery") : require("jquery")(b)), a(c), c
} : a(jQuery)
}(function(a) {
"use strict";
a.extend(a.ZeEditor.DEFAULTS, {

    //  DROPDOWN LIST MADE FROM THE keyii_name VARIABLE
    itemKey: keyii_name, 

    itemKeySelection: !1
}),  a.ZeEditor.PLUGINS.itemKey = function(b) {
    function c(c) {

       // INSERT '{{ chosen value }}' 
       b.selection.remove(), b.html.insert("{{" + a + "}}");
    }
    return {
        apply: c
    }
}, a.ZeEditor.RegisterCommand("itemKey", {
    type: "dropdown",
    title: "Font Size",
    html: function() {

       // THIS HASNT BEEN CHANGED BY ME IT MIGHT BE WHERE I AM GOING WRONG
        for (var a = '<ul class="fr-dropdown-list">', b = this.opts.itemKey, c = 0; c < b.length; c++) {
            var d = b[c];
            a += '<li><a class="fr-command" data-cmd="itemKey" data-param1="' + d + '" title="' + d + '">' + d + "</a></li>"
        }
        return a += "</ul>"
    },
    callback: function(a, b) {
        this.itemKey.apply(b)
    },

}), a.ZeEditor.DefineIcon("itemKey", {
    NAME: "text-height"
})
});
```

I can only assume there is more I need to change for this to work. This js is a bit above me and I'm still learning more complicated js like this (thus the reason I'm  doing this).

Would appreciate the help on this one.

Comment: a guess: `.insert("{{" + c + "}}");` (instead of a)

Comment: @dandavis YES! it works now. thanks! Post it as an answer and ill give it to you :)